# Полная загрузка страницы php simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Требуется полная загрузка страницы. Один блок на сайте подгружается в течении 3-5 секунд после полной загрузки **#tab-3** Вот сам сайт http://ru.ariston-pro.com/product/3300849/#models-464

```
 $i = 0;
    $tovar_number = count($links) - 1;
    while ($i <= $tovar_number) {
        $html_product = file_get_html( htmlspecialchars_decode($links[$i++]) );
        $links_product = array();

        $links_product['_NAME_KOTLE_'] = trim($html_product->find('#tab-3',0)->outertext);


        $links_product = str_replace("&quot;",'',$links_product);
        $articles[] = $links_product;


    }
```

Comment: вопрос то в чем?

Comment: @teran, Нужно что-бы парсился блок  #tab-3 с содержимым. Сейчас этого не происходит из за того что после загрузки страницы он подгружается.